# Why is std::set::lower_bound(x) (effectively) defined as the smallest number >= x rather than the largest number <= x?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the technical definition of `lower bound` but I would expect if I had a set `a = { 0, 3, 4 }` and computed the `a.lower_bound(2)` that the result would be `0`. I.e. I would expect `std::set::lower_bound` to be close to the mathematical concept of [infimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum)

And yet the standard library defines it as the largest number not less than (effectively `>=`) x.

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: It probably is more common to think in terms of ranges of iterators, so the iterator return is the lower "barrier" of when you say "I want everything between 2 and 5". The question though is, why would you expect it to be otherwise? What is /your/ reasoning behind it?

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer, you can just get the infimum by using `std::prev(iter)` if `*iter != x`.

Comment: Corrections — "…the standard library defines it as the **smallest** number not less than…" @KonradRudolph's suggestion is good but first you also need to check the `set` isn't empty. For the `std::lower_bound` free function, you can also use `reverse_iterator`s and `std::greater` to reverse the direction of "error".

Comment: Ah, the elegant way is to construct a `std::set::reverse_iterator` from the result of `s.lower_bound(x)` and then compare that to `s.rend()`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "`[lower|upper]_bound`" functions are meant to return a place in a set where you could insert a key that would not violate the ordering of the set. Because an iterator of an STL set points to before the next element, if `lower_bound(2)` returned an iterator to `0`, then inserting `2` would violate the order of your set, it would now be `{2, 0, 3, 4}`. Upper bound serves to show the last place you could insert without violating set order.

This is most useful if your set may have duplicate key entries. Consider `{0, 3, 3, 4}`. `lower_bound(3)` would return an iterator to here: `{0, *, 3, 3, 4}`, while `upper_bound(3)` would return it here: `{0, 3, 3, *, 4}`.

Answer (score 6):

It may help to consider the behavior of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` together.

In the STL, ranges are always closed-open intervals.  The range delimited by two iterators, `first` and `last`, includes all of the elements between `first` and `last`, including `first` and excluding `last`.  Using interval notation, we'd represent this as `[first, last)`.

`lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are defined such that they find the *range* of elements that compare equal to the specified value.  If you iterate between `lower_bound(x)` and `upper_bound(x)`, you will iterate over all of the elements that compare equal to `x`.  If no element is equal to `x`, then it is guaranteed that `lower_bound(x) == upper_bound(x)`.

This feature is less important for `std::map`, which has at most one element for every key, but is a very useful feature for non-unique associative containers and for the nonmember `std::lower_bound` that may be used with arbitrary sequences of sorted elements.

[Note that if you want to obtain *both* the lower and upper bound, you should call `equal_range` instead, which returns both.]

Comment: Perhaps more significantly, if you iterate between `lower_bound(n)` and `upper_bound(m)`, you will visit all of the elements in the range `[n...m)`.